# How to check if my all promises are fulfilled

Tags: javascript, promise

Currently I am writing a block of code.
I want to start webcamera when video will start play and stop camera when video is paused but before loading camera I want to check if my all models are loaded or not. I want to load the model once until page refresh.**thats totaly a seprate case that if user page refersh it will load again**. Now if I click on play button in video it starts my camera. How can i configure it in a way where if user pause the button it only disable the camera and press play button it only load the camera (not load my models again).

```
    <html>
 <head>
     <title>Video detecting and emotion storing in database</title>
     <script type="text/css" defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
     <script type="text/css" src="style.css"></script>
     <script defer type="text/javascript" src="script/face-api.min.js"></script>
     <script defer type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
     <style>
         #livecam{
             height: 400px;
             width: 600px;
             float: right;

         }
     </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="container">
            <video id="myvideo" src="laravel.mp4" controls height="400" width="600" >
            </video>

        <video id="livecam" autoplay muted height="400" width="600" ></video>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

..................................... Index.php

now my script.js

```
   var video = document.getElementById('myvideo');
const liveview = document.getElementById('livecam');
const height = 400;
const width = 600;


Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
])

video.onplaying = function(){
    enablewebcam();
    alert("Video is playing");
};

video.onpause = function(){
    disablecam();
}
function enablewebcam(){
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:{width:600, height:400},
        audio:false}).then((stream) => {
        liveview.srcObject = stream;
    })
};


function disablecam(){
    liveview.srcObject = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if your models have already been loaded before enabling the webcam, you can use a flag variable that is set to true after the models are loaded. Then, in your `enablewebcam` function, you can check the value of this flag before enabling the webcam:

```
let modelsLoaded = false;

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
]).then(() => {
  modelsLoaded = true;
});

function enablewebcam() {
  if (modelsLoaded) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { width: 600, height: 400 }, audio: false }).then((stream) => {
      liveview.srcObject = stream;
    });
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.isLoaded()` function to check if the `tinyFaceDetector` model has been loaded. If it has, you can assume that all the models have been loaded, since they are all being loaded in the same Promise.all block.

```
function enablewebcam() {
  if (faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.isLoaded()) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { width: 600, height: 400 }, audio: false }).then((stream) => {
      liveview.srcObject = stream;
    });
  }
}
```

Either way, you can use the `video.onpause` event to stop the webcam when the video is paused, as you have already done in your code.

Comment: First of all thanks @Ritik for your answer but I think you didn't understand my question. I am saying I want to load the model once but I want to play with the camera object with the video . like if video is paused camera shut down. if video play camera on but I want to check that all model loads before the camera starts first time.

Comment: you need to save the returned data from promises in some variable otherwise you can't

Comment: Yes thats the idea I came up. can you help me to write the chunk of code. I am thinking if all promises are resolved then it will set a variable to true. and before enabling the camera i will pass that variable in the my enablewebcam function so it will check if its already true. it will turn it on.

Comment: @Ritin can you guide me with chunk of code.                                                                                     Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
])           lets say A var modelstatus will be set true if all models are loaded successfully. how I can do that

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the models have loaded when the user clicks play, delay adding the `controls` attribute until after the models have been fetched.

If you do this in a `then` handler of the `Promise.all` call, you can add event listeners to the video element to start and stop the video in the same place - the user can then start and stop the video at will. You may want to get rid of the `alert` message` however.

The snippet has been cut down for testing but unfortunately does not work on Stack overflow:

```js
"use strict";
var video = document.getElementById('myvideo');
const liveview = document.getElementById('livecam');
const height = 400;
const width = 600;

Promise.all([
 // production
   // faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
   // faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
   // faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
   // faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
 // testing
   Promise.resolve(true),
   Promise.resolve(true),
   Promise.resolve(true),
   Promise.resolve(true)
])

.then( ()=> {
    video.onplaying = function(){
        enablewebcam();
        alert("Video is playing");
    };
    video.onpause = function(){
        disablecam();
    }
    // show video controls:
    video.setAttribute("controls", "");

    function enablewebcam(){
          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:{width:600, height:400},
            audio:false})
          .then((stream) => {
            liveview.srcObject = stream;
          })
          .catch( err => { 
            console.log("no cam, ", err.message)
          });
      };

    function disablecam(){
        liveview.srcObject = null;
    }

})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    alert("Something went wrong");
});
```

```css
video { border: thin solid blue}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <video id="myvideo"
     src="https://i.imgur.com/LTc02xw_lq.mp4"
     height="400" width="600">
    </video>
    <video id="livecam" autoplay muted height="400" width="600" ></video>
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciated your time. Well by this can also be done. but I found it very easy way. Using a simple variable. Right now I am in beginning stage but for future purpose I will surely change my code according to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of promises because the `Promise` class has an `all` method that receives an array of promises and returns the result once they are all fullfilled. If you think that one of the promises could fail, you should instead use `allSettled` because the `all` method returns Pending if one of the promises fails.

The `allSettled` method will return the promises data with a `status` and a `value` field. `status` giving you fullfilled or rejected and `value` giving you the promise data.

An example of this would be:

```
// Your array of promises
promises = [
...
]

// 'all' method
Promises.all(promises)
.then(data => console.log(data))

// 'allSettled' method
Promises.allSettled(promises)
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: FIrst of all thanks Lazlomeli for your time but what i am asking is little different then your answer,

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer as Hint by Ritik

Setting a variable true after successfull loading of model and everytime before enabling the camera will check that variable if it true or false.

```
    Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/mmodels'),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
]).then(function(){
    modeloadedstatus = true;
})
```

---

checking modeloadedstatus before everytime enabling camera

```
 video.onplaying = function(){
    if(modeloadedstatus) {
        enablewebcam();
        console.log(modeloadedstatus)
        alert("Video is playing");
    } else{
        alert("Error in model loading");
    }
    };
```